# MDX using IIF and SUM

Tags: filter, mdx, exists, iif

At the following `MDX` code I want to get the aggregate of measure only for  members that are in the specified last time (like in example 01/06/2015), else I don't want them .
I tried existing and exists but without any luck.
I believe i have to use the `IIF` function 
like:

```
IIF DAYTIME, MEASURE D NOT NULL THEN AGGREGATE....
```

(if for the specific month, measure D is bigger than 0 then SUM measure D for the specific time range)

```
ELSE NULL.
```

(Else not print it on output)

And then filter E.members where `SUM` measure `D >1` ON ROWS.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER A AS 
    b + C 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Aggregate] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
        DAYTIME.[Month].&[2013-01-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [DAYTIME].[Month].&[2015-06-01T00:00:00]
     ,[Measures].[D]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Aggregate] ON 0
 ,Filter
  (
    Exists
    (
      [E].MEMBERS
     ,[DAYTIME].[Month].&[2015-06-01T00:00:00]
    )
   ,
    [Measures].[Aggregate] > 1
  ) ON 1
FROM [CUBE];
```

Comment: what does `MEMBER A` have to do with your requirements?

Comment: Nothing at all in the question, I am using as a filter.I have a thought: add a SET AS in the beginng like filter [E].members where measures.D >0 and are in [DAYTIME].[Month].&[2015-06-01T00:00:00] 2) c

Answer (score 0):

Someone from MSDN forums reminded me the use of NONEMPTY. So first I used NONEMPTY like 
Nonempty ( [E] , ( [DAYTIME].[Month].&[2015-06-01T00:00:00], [measures].[D] ) )
in order to return all E.Members who had an non-null value for measure.D on 2015-06-01
Then I filter this with another measure

I don't get correct data but I believe there is problem inside BI solution.

Comment: Seems a little strange - your measure `[Measures].[Aggregate]` already includes this date `[DAYTIME].[Month].&[2015-06-01T00:00:00]` therefore the filter `Filter( ... [Measures].[Aggregate] > 1)` will already be performing a `nonEmpty` operation on `[E].MEMBERS` for the date `[DAYTIME].[Month].&[2015-06-01T00:00:00]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Sum` rather than `Aggregate`. Also as `[DAYTIME].[Month].&[2015-06-01T00:00:00]` is part of the measure `[Measures].[Aggregate]` you could delete the `Exists` function:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Aggregate] AS 
    Sum
    (
        DAYTIME.[Month].&[2013-01-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [DAYTIME].[Month].&[2015-06-01T00:00:00]
     ,[Measures].[D]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Aggregate] ON 0
 ,Filter
  (
    [E].MEMBERS
   ,[Measures].[Aggregate] > 1
  ) ON 1
FROM [CUBE];
```

Note: it is important that `[Measures].[D]` is related to these members `[E].MEMBERS`