# Count Working Days MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I would like to count the working days of a spesific time range and then find the Average Daily Dispatches.Currently the time range is at WHERE statement.
 I believe that I have include the date range in the 1st Member but I can't figure how to count the dates in a month range.
Any suggestments?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Working Days] AS
COUNT(Date.[Working Date].&[1])--Doesn't work
MEMBER [Measures].[Average Daily Dispatches] AS
[Measures].[Total Dispatches]/[Measures].[Working Days]
SELECT [Measures].[Average Daily Dispatches] ON 0
FROM [cube]
WHERE (
[Date].[Month].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]:[Date].[Month].&[2015-08-01T00:00:00]
);
```

Comment: Did any of our answers help you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NonEmpty` function to yield those working dates on which there was a dispatch. Then use `COUNT` on top of this.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Working Days] AS
COUNT
    (
    NonEmpty
            (
             [Date].[Working Date].MEMBERS, 
             [Measures].[Total Dispatches]
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of alternative seems to exist using `Exists/Existing` (I think 1 is Monday in the AdvWrks cube!)

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MondayCnt] AS 
    Count
    (
      Exists
      (
        (EXISTING 
          [Date].[Calendar].MEMBERS)
       ,[Date].[Day of Week].[1]
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Averge] AS 
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] / [Measures].[MondayCnt] 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[MondayCnt]
   ,[Measures].[Averge]
  } ON 0
 ,
    [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[6]
  : 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2007]&[6] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The above results in the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts!MSDN forum gave me the above answer and it's right!

Comment: @Proffesore I wrote the above yesterday. Is it also on `msdn`?

Comment: @Proffesore It's a simple etiquette here on this site that if somebody helps you, you give them an up vote or if it answers it, you mark it as an answer. On the other hand, if it doesn't help you, let the person know about it along with issue you faced. That way, the person answering it stands to benefit and improve the answer. Cheers.

Comment: @SouravA well said Sir. Proffesore prefers MSDN which is fine - good to remember in the future. This question of his was also apparently answered via MSDN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854424/mdx-using-iif-and-sum/31856709#31856709

Comment: @whytheq I posted the same question on MSDN and they reply with the same( I don't imply that you copied, I just share it with you).Thanks for the reply@SouravA I tried to vote for the answer, but I have less than 15 rep and my votes aren't public for now

Comment: @Proffesore. I am happy that my attempt is the same as MSDN forum as that forum is a bit more advanced than mdx within SO. If an answer is an answer then hit the tick mark (it will turn green)...this shows that it is your used answer. You will also receive reputation points for marking an answer as correct.